# Organize routes into separate files not working properly in Slim

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

This is my **Index.php** file:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
//User Routes
require '../src/routes/users.php'; // This not working
require '../src/routes/org.php'; // Only This working

$app->run();
```

**.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When there is only one require file it's working fine but when adding two or multiple files then only last one working and others giving **page not found error**. I'm new in slim and PHP so I have no idea what's wrong.

**users.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * User: y34h1a
 * Date: 2/10/17
 * Time: 3:47 AM
 */
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

//Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/users', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $sql = "Select * from users";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $users['users'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($users);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});


//GET SINGLE USER
$app->get('/api/user/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $sql = "Select * from users WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $user['user'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($user);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});


//ADD USER
$app->post('/api/user/add', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $name = $request->getParam('name');
    $email = $request->getParam('email');
    $password = $request->getParam('password');
    $sql = "Insert into users(name,email, password) values (:name, :email, :password)";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Customer Added"}}';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

//UPDATE USER

$app->put('/api/user/update/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $name = $request->getParam('name');
    $email = $request->getParam('email');
    $password = $request->getParam('password');

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET 
              name = :name, 
              email = :email, 
              password = :password 
            WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Customr UPDATED"}}';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});


//DELETE USER
$app->get('/api/user/delete/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

**org.php**

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

//Get All Orgs
$app->get('/api/orgs', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $sql = "Select * from org";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $users['orgs'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($users);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

//GET SINGLE ORG
$app->get('/api/org/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $sql = "Select * from org WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $user['org'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($user);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});



//ADD ORG
$app->post('/api/org/add', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $user_id = $request->getParam('user_id');
    $name = $request->getParam('name');
    $address = $request->getParam('address');
    $sql = "Insert into org(user_id, name, address) values (:user_id, :name, :address)";
    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':address', $address);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Organization Added"}}';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});


//UPDATE ORG
$app->put('/api/org/update/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $name = $request->getParam('name');
    $address = $request->getParam('address');

    $sql = "UPDATE org SET 
              name = :name, 
              address = :address 
            WHERE id = $id";
    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':address', $address);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Organization Deleted"}}';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

//DELETE ORG
$app->delete('/api/org/delete/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $user_id = $request->getParam('user_id');
    $org_id = $request->getParam('org_id');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM org WHERE id = $id AND user_id = $user_id";
    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Sheet Deleted"}}';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please show content of `'../src/routes/users.php'`?

Comment: code added @GeorgyIvanov

Comment: users.php working properly when index.php has only this file. but when adding org.php or 2-3 more class only working last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, your problem is that you basically create three instances of application: one in `index.php`, one in `users.php`, one in `org.php`.

Application instance is created by

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

And that application is launched by `$app->run`.

In `index.php` you have `$app`, which is overriten by `$app` in `users.php`, then overwritten by `$app` in `org.php`.

This is the reason why `require '../src/routes/users.php';` seems to be ignored - it's declaring `$app`, adds routes and in the next file you overwrite `$app` and add routes.

To fix this, simply remove

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

from everywhere but `index.php`.