# Last require in index.php only work for routes

Tags: slim

I am creating API in SLIM in which i have included two routes files customers.php and books.php. books.php route file is working properly but when i run customers.php routes it says 404 error.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        //'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
        'debug' => true 
    ],
];
$app = new \Slim\App($config);


//$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

// Customer routes
require '../src/routes/customers.php';  //this route file does not work
require '../src/routes/books.php';  //this route file work

$app->run();
```

Comment: I guess you are declaring new instance of `Slim\App` in every file. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes i am declaring new instance in every file. Then what is the problem can you explain.

Comment: There was someone with the same problem, take a look at the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174522/6850820

Comment: Thanks @Georgy Ivanov  you saved my day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organize routes into separate files not working properly in Slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174121/organize-routes-into-separate-files-not-working-properly-in-slim)